# How do I add Risc Os to a NOOBs install on Pi Zero (ie no wired net)

Tags: pi-zero, noobs, riscos

It's driving me up the wall, but I can't find a solution to this. I've got a Raspberry Pi Zero, and I'd like to put Risc OS on it. Grabbing the Risc OS 99meg install file and using Win32DiskImager to SD card it onto the Zero did nothing. Black screen. Installing NOOBS did work however. NOOBS has a Shift key boot option that should allow selection of different OSes - but it doesn't show any alternative OSes (apart from Raspbian). I think this is because the PiZero has no wired connection, and the wifi dongle hasn't yet been booted up. So there's no way to choose an OS.

Very grateful if anybody has a solution - or perhaps the Raspberry Pi Zero simply can't run RiscOS

Comment: As an aside - I've tried creating a folder called RISC OS inside the os part of NOOBS, on the SD card. Inside it I put files found here [link](http://downloads.raspberrypi.org/riscos/) (not including archive and images), but it doesn't show up on the NOOBS shift screen

Comment: It may be that the zero can't handle it.  Have you tried the RiscOs Pico version?

Answer (score 1):

NOOBS needs an internet connection for it to display all the other OSs that are available. For some reason, on the PI3, the latest NOOBS no longer has RISCOS